# Trigger maximum memory consumption with openssl

Tags: linux, bash, openssl, aes

The code below, shows the average time of the 5 repetitions from `openssl`. Using the same idea, how can I get maximum memory consumption?

```
#!/bin/sh
SUM=0
for i in {1..5}
do
t=$((/usr/bin/time -f '%e' openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -K 1234567890 -in t -out g 1> /dev/null) 2>&1)
SUM=`bc <<< "$SUM + $t"`
done
res= bc <<< "scale=4; $SUM / 5"
echo $res
```